# canOpenURL error with vKontakte sdk

Tags: ios, social-networking, vk

i am getting this error : 
**-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "vkauthorize://authorize" - error: "(null)"**

even thought i used this as the documentation suggested. I hace also added App Trasnport exception.

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
<string>vk</string>
<string>vkauthorize</string>
</array>
```

I dont know anything else to try.

Comment: That simply means you don't have the corresponding app installed. It's benign and can be ignored.

Comment: I created an app in vKontakte , and i am using the correct app id.

Comment: Your app is calling `canOpenURL:` with a URL that has the `vkauthorize` scheme. `canOpenURL:` is returning `NO` and the message in the log indicates that `canOpenURL:` is returning `NO` because you don't have any app installed that responds to that custom URL scheme.

Comment: Oh you mean the vKontakted ios app. How can i fix it for those who dont have the app installed ?

Comment: There's nothing to fix. The error simply means the app isn't installed. If `canOpenURL` returns `NO` then you know the app isn't installed. Add code to handle the case as needed.

Comment: In other social medias like facebook , if the user doesnt have the app in his phone , it opens safari. Is it possible to do it here ?